# Degraded Synology volume even though all drives report normal

Tags: synology-diskstation

I recently upgraded two hard drives on my Synology DS-412+.  When the volume expansion completed, DSM now reports that the volume/storage pool is degraded but all three drives in the storage pool report normal status.  As well I get this log message: "Storage pool 1 (Group1) on MEDIA has degraded [3/4]".  I can't see any way to repair the storage pool or understand why DSM thinks its degraded.

Comment: Does your RAID storage pool support being repaired?   You have not provided enough information to diagnose your true issue.  

https://www.synology.com/en-global/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/StorageManager/storage_pool_repair

Comment: I don't get an option to repair.  It's greyed out when I select the storage pool.

Comment: Why is it saying 3/4 - Could it think there are meant to be 4 disks in the array?

Comment: I wondered the same things, although I can't find anything in the documentation that explains what that 3/4 means.  It was never a 4 disk array.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, when I replaced a completely failed drive with a larger capacity drive, Storage Manager added the replaced drive to the storage pool instead of replacing the failed drive in the storage pool.  I probably made a pilot error somewhere, but not sure where exactly.  Sure would be nice if storage manager told you it was missing a drive instead of just reporting degraded.